# Apache Zookeeper data persistence. Do nodes created with CreateMode.Persistent survive full cluster restarts?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am creating nodes using the apache curator library on windows using CreateMode.Persistent. After a full cluster restart, I notice that sometimes the nodes are present. At other times they are not. Does Zookeeper guarantee the nodes created such to be persisted across restarts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a node with CreateMode.PERSISTENT and the method successfully returns then you are guaranteed that a quorum of nodes (n/2+1) have received and persisted the node. Restarting the cluster will not affect this. If you're seeing the node disappear then maybe a) you are using an async API to create the node and are not getting a success response; b) you're somehow wiping the data directory when you restart your cluster; c) ??